# Missing files from Books

Tags: ipad, catalina, books

My wife has lost a number of files she had in iBooks on her iPad.
These were journal articles downloaded from the web or books/patterns she had purchased on line.
Many are no longer available for download.

The presumed cause is when she plugged the iPad into her MacBookPro to backup and upgrade iPadOS.
Books seems to delete any which are downloaded directly to the iPad.
If you elect to turn off Books sync it threatens to delete all the books on the iPad.

This seems like a catch 22 - there seems to no way to sync downloaded Books to the MacBook (which she doesn't really want to do - because there is insufficient space on the SSD) but turning sync off deletes all the books!

I would like to recover the lost files - some older files would be in the TimeMachine backup and possible in the iPad backup.

Can anyone suggest

1. a method of recovering these files?
2. How to stop sync deleting downloaded files.